# provide data into <tag> xml xml </tag> for a C# web service

Tags: c#, xml

I have a method in C# .NET 4.0 web service which accepts DataTable as on of the ByVal parameter.
This method is now being used in an xml application.
So, in the place of the datatable, I am getting as `<Meta> xml xml </Meta>`.
How should I pass the data in the form of xml to be able to use by datatable within the xml below?

I haven't found proper solutions for this on web.

```
POST /MyService/service.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: xxxxxxxxxxxxx
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/Upload"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Upload xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <IndexKey>string</IndexKey>
      <YoMoney_Key>string</YoMoney_Key>
      <buffer>base64Binary</buffer>
      <strDocType>string</strDocType>
      <append>boolean</append>
      <revtype>string</revtype>
      <strScanDateTime>string</strScanDateTime>
      <UserID>string</UserID>
      <Meta>xmlxml</Meta>
    </Upload>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: simply you have to map your xml to c# DataTable right?

Comment: yes. I accept datatable but I must pass it as xml.

Comment: yes you need to pass your xml to datatable.

Comment: is this sufficient to provide you,  to import your xml to datatable and then you access each row in datatable

Comment: The code in my query is how I pass the data as xml, but how do I pass data for "xml xml" inside <meta></meta> is I am confused with.
That particular xml data will be taken as DataTable in my WebService Method.
So, basically, I am confused how do I pass it in xml format.